# using acher tag in next js for seo : concatiate html and javascript tag

Tags: next.js

[image]

what am i doing error here

i tryed `<a href="https://wixten.com/query/"+item.id >` but its giving error as in the image

i tryed singele qoutes also but that also gave me error

is there anything i am missing

i tryed `<a href="https://wixten.com/query/"+item.id >` but its giving error as in the image

i tryed singele qoutes also but that also gave me error

is there anything i am missing

Comment: Please do not post images of code, anything text-based should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

as per jsx rule you need curly braces for value of attribute

```
<a href={"https://wixten.com/query/"+item.id}>
```